# How to "Like" in Show Page? [Error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
NoMethodError in Valuations#show
undefined method `each' for #<Valuation:0x007fb6e9a62c08>
Line: <% @valuation.each do |valuation| %>
```

How should we define it in the controller so that a user can "Like" a valuation in the show page?

**controller**

```
def show
  @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @valuation
  @comments = @commentable.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def like
  @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
  @valuation_like = current_user.valuation_likes.build(valuation: @valuation)
  if @valuation_like.save
    @valuation.increment!(:likes)
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
  end  
    redirect_to(:back)
end
```

Liking on **show**:

```
<% @valuation.each do |valuation| %>
    <%= pluralize(valuation.likes, 'like') %>
  <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up') + 
        ' Like it', like_valuation_path(:id => valuation.id), method: :post %>
    <% valuation.likers.each do |user| %>
     <%= user.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There is a valuation and a valuation_like **model**.

```
class ValuationLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :valuation }
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :liked_comment, class_name: 'Valuation', foreign_key: :valuation_id
end

class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valuation_likes 
  has_many :likers, through: :valuation_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
end
```

Comment: `@valuation` is a single object, it has no `each` method.  Just remove the outer `each/do/end` block and fix the reference from `valuation` to `@valuation`.  It will get you to your next issue at least.

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a single item, the `find` method returns 1 `Valuation` object, or throws when it doesn't find it:

```
@valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
```

So when you try to do this:

```
<% @valuation.each do |valuation| %>
```

The interpreter gets mad, a single `Valuation` has no `each` method, as this warning tells you:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Valuation:0x007fb6e9a62c08>
```

So instead of iterating over the `@valuation` object, just use it:

```
<%= pluralize(@valuation.likes, 'like') %>
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up') + 
            ' Like it', like_valuation_path(:id => @valuation.id), method: :post %>
<% @valuation.likers.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

And you can probably avoid using `content_tag` in your views (that's more of a helper thing).  The `link_to` function can take a block for its content, so try something like this:

```
<%= pluralize(@valuation.likes, 'like') %>
<%= link_to like_valuation_path(:id => @valuation.id), method: :post do %>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> Like it
<% end %>
<% @valuation.likers.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying to me a concept that I should have remembered but didn't fully understand to begin with! And I definitely like it with link_to more too Nick :)